# Column Ambiguously Defined

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm getting:

> ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
>   00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"

Whenever I try to run:

```
select 
first_name as student_first_name, 
last_name as student_last_name

from super_student ss

inner join sub_distance_learning sdl
on sdl.student_id = ss.id

inner join sub_academic_tutor sat
on sat.id = sdl.academic_tutor_id

inner join super_sub_lecturer ssl
on ssl.id = sat.lecturer_id

inner join super_employee se
on se.id = ssl.employee_id;
```

The error only shows when this is included:

```
inner join super_employee se
on se.id = ssl.employee_id;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, more than one table has `first_name` and/or `last_name` in it, presumably `super_student` and `super_employee`.

Use the table aliases that you nicely defined:

```
select ss.first_name as student_first_name, 
       ss.last_name as student_last_name
```