# Getting Column Ambiguously Defined in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle, when adding where clause with the below query, I get an error

> Column ambiguously defined

Query:

```
SELECT
    t1.*, t2.*
FROM
    NM_APPLICATION t1
LEFT JOIN 
    NM_QUOTA t2 ON t2.QUOTA_ID = t1.QUOTA_ID
WHERE
    ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y'
ORDER BY
    MERIT_POSITION DESC
```

Please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Column Ambiguously Defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162565/column-ambiguously-defined)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the issue here is that both tables `NM_APPLICATION` and `NM_QUOTA` have a column called `ACTIVE_FLAG`.  The remedy is to decide which table's column you want to use, and then provide an alias to that table:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM NM_APPLICATION t1
LEFT JOIN NM_QUOTA t2
    ON t2.QUOTA_ID = t1.QUOTA_ID
WHERE t1.ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y'        -- or t2.ACTIVE_FLAG
ORDER BY MERIT_POSITION DESC
```

By the way, if this answer be correct, then it might indicate a design problem that two tables in the same schema have a column which might be storing the same or similar data.  So, you might want to rethink your table design.

Comment: *"t might indicate a design problem"* In my experience, if one table in a schema has a column like `ACTIVE_FLAG` then most or all of the tables have it. Because that's how they've decided to handle versioning.

Comment: @APC I said that without thinking too much.  Yes...I could see that maybe it is some kind of soft deletion column.

Answer (score 3):

You need prefix columns `ACTIVE_FLAG` or/and  `MERIT_POSITION` by `t1` or `t2` alias if exists in both table